# Code for the keyboard to be dismissed is setup but it is still not working?

Tags: ios, swift

I have done everything that I thought of but when i run this code the keyboard appears but still does not go away on either a tap or the return button. Can someone help me?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var Label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var Label2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.textField.delegate = self          
    }        

    //Hide keyboard when user touches outside keyboard
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    //Presses return key
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure this ViewController is assigned to your view in the ViewController custom class field of the property editor (Assuming storyboard)?

Comment: @ptoinson what do you mean?

Comment: @ptoinson yes it is it is linked to this view controller. Do you have any thing else that might be causing it not to work?

Comment: Set a breakpoint on your call to resign first responder. Is it definitely being called?

Comment: @Fogmeister what do you mean?

Comment: I don't know how else to explain it. Put a breakpoint in the "text field should return" function on the line for "resign first responder". Is the breakpoint hit? Does it stop your app?

Comment: You can also just add a log statement in the textFieldShouldReturn and viewDidLoad methods to see if it's wired correctly. NSLog("textFieldShouldReturn") and NSLog("viewDidLoad") respectfully.

Comment: For breakpoints, goto your source code in the editor and if you double click over by the line numbers on the left of the code, it will add a blue mark. This tells the debugger to stop at than lin so you can inspec it.

Comment: @ptoinson it still will not work and i tried the breakpoints and it did not stop also the controllers are all linked

Comment: If it did not stop at the breakpoint then you have not connected something up properly. Did you set the subclass in the storyabord properly?

Comment: @Fogmeister what do you mean i have the controller linked to the subclass in the code

Comment: Hmm. Not sure what to say from there. Sorry. Did you definitely connect the text field to the IBOutlet from the storyboard? Can you show a screenshot of the storyboard?

Comment: @Fogmeister can you talk on twitter?

Comment: you definitely got something wired up wrong. add more pictures. i can also do a skype session.

Comment: @ptoinson i can't Skype but i can talk on Skype my Skype is mechmatt01

Comment: skype does not seem to be finding you. I'm ptoinson on skype.

Comment: @ptoinson i sent you a request

Comment: just replied. was in my kitchen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't show an image in the comments so I created an answer. I was able to get this working with very little effort. I added a controller, Added the custom class, outlets and pretty much added your exact code. Sometimes I forget to add the custom class. Perhaps that is it.

[image: Setting the Custom Class]

Answer (score 0):

Better not use `touchesBegan`. One method which will surely work:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var Label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var Label2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.textField.delegate = self

        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.didTapBackground))
        tapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func didTapBackground() {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }

    //Presses return key

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return(true)
    }

}
```

Observe that I also set the `cancelTouchesInView` to `false` to let other buttons or UITapGestureRecognizers to correctly do their job.